# Django resize image before sending to client

Tags: python, django, image, resize

I have the following view on my django server :

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_post_image(request, postID):
    response_date = {}
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        response_date['code'] = 507
        response_date['msg'] = "not logged in"
    else:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=postID)
        image_data = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + post.pic.name, "rb").read()
        return HttpResponse(image_data,
                            content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(post.pic.name))
```

which takes an postID and return its image. but I want to resize this image (without changing ratio) before send it to client.

How is it possible?

Comment: Resizing images can be computationally heavy, especially depending on the original. So I wouldn't recommend this approach of resizing an image right before sending it to the client, I'd recommend to store an extra resized version of an image when it is uploaded and then send that to the client, which won't even require a special view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy-thumbnails provides the [easy way of generating thumbnails](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/usage/#non-django-file-objects).

Answer (score 1):

for the raw tool for manipulating images from python see:
https://pillow.readthedocs.org/

...for a Django-integrated image resizing system see:
http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
or
http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ (note the requirements though)

Comment: `sorl.thumbnail` saves generated thumbnail to the file and key store. If you want to do all resizing in memory then `easy-thumbnails` can do it.

Comment: agreed, I actually prefer easy-thumbnails too, the k/v store requirement of sorl-thumbnail is annoying... I always used to use the old version of sorl